# CSS animation (position) not smooth

Tags: css, css-animations

I made a subtle background movement, but the effect isn't that pleasing. While moving it kinda jerks, you can see the image move pixel by pixel.

How can I change this so it becomes a nice smooth animation.

**The Code (https://jsfiddle.net/38tf0j21/):**

```css
body {
  padding:50px;
  margin 0;
  height:100vh;
}
.landing_img_container {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  width: calc(100% - 100px);
  height: 100%;
  animation-name: start_animation;
  animation-delay: 1s;
  animation-direction: normal;
  animation-duration: 5s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-timing-function: ease;
}
.landing_img {
  position: absolute;
  top:  0;
  left:   0;
  bottom: 0;
  right:  0;
  background-color:red;
}
@keyframes start_animation {
  0% {
    left: 100px;
  }
  100% {
    left: 50px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="landing_img_container">
  <div class="landing_img"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work like you expect it to: https://jsfiddle.net/38tf0j21/2/

This is using the `transform` property instead of `left`

Comment: Thanks! Exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

For smooth CSS position animations you need use `transform: translate3d` property.

[See this example](https://jsfiddle.net/38tf0j21/1/)