# How can I change my jQuery code to make a div follow my cursor smoothly?

Tags: jquery, css

I have some jQuery code that makes a circle shaped span follow my cursor. It works, however I've seen another one on a different website that uses `transform: translate()` instead of `top` and `left` properties when moving the cursor around and it's quite a bit smoother as the cursor moves around.

Can anyone show me how I can edit this code to use `transform: translate()`?

**JSFiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/oj70y5Lm/

**CSS, JQuery and HTML**

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

  var mouseX = 0, mouseY = 0;
  var xp = 0, yp = 0;

  $(document).mousemove(function(e){
    mouseX = e.pageX - 20;
    mouseY = e.pageY - 20; 
  });

  setInterval(function(){
    xp += ((mouseX - xp)/3);
    yp += ((mouseY - yp)/3);
    $("#circle").css({left: xp +'px', top: yp +'px'});
  }, 20);

});
```

```css
body, html {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%; 
  width : 100%;  
  margin: 0;
}

.circle {
    position: absolute;
    background: #000000;
    opacity: .075;
  width: 40px; 
  height: 40px; 
    border-radius: 50%;  
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="circle" class="circle"></span>
```

Comment: You can add `transition: top 0.5s, left 0.5s;`, but it was doing some strange things for me so not worthy of an answer.  Probably needs some other values changed.

Comment: Not a very good existing answer, but maybe this will help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36531317/2181514

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using JS with 20ms interval try using CSS transition. CSS is always much smoother than timed JS

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

  var mouseX = 0, mouseY = 0;
  var xp = 0, yp = 0;

  $(document).mousemove(function(e){
    mouseX = e.pageX - 20;
    mouseY = e.pageY - 20;
    
    xp += ((mouseX - xp)/3);
    yp += ((mouseY - yp)/3);
    $("#circle").css({left: xp +'px', top: yp +'px'});
  });
});
```

```css
body, html {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%; 
  width : 100%;  
  margin: 0;
}

.circle {
    position: absolute;
    background: #000000;
    opacity: .075;
  width: 40px; 
  height: 40px; 
    border-radius: 50%;  
    pointer-events: none;
    transition: left 20ms ease-in-out, top 20ms ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="circle" class="circle"></span>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer Justinas, I tried this and it didn't really have the same effect as the 20ms interval. Do you think that a cubic bezier would help? I quite like the slight delay that the 20ms interval gives and would make it longer/ more pronounced if I knew how.

Answer (score 0):

I've worked out how to do it :)

I've changed this line: `$("#circle").css({left: xp +'px', top: yp +'px'});`

to:

`$("#circle").css('transform', 'translate(' + xp + 'px, ' + yp + 'px)');`

**JSFiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/oj70y5Lm/1/

**CSS, JQuery and HTML**

```
<span id="circle" class="circle"></span>


body, html {
    position: relative;
    height: 100%; 
    width : 100%;  
    margin: 0;
}

.circle {
    position: absolute;
    background: #000000;
    opacity: .075;
    width: 40px; 
    height: 40px; 
    border-radius: 50%;  
    pointer-events: none;
}

jQuery(document).ready(function() {

  var mouseX = 0, mouseY = 0;
  var xp = 0, yp = 0;

  $(document).mousemove(function(e){
    mouseX = e.pageX - 20;
    mouseY = e.pageY - 20; 
  });

  setInterval(function(){
    xp += ((mouseX - xp)/3);
    yp += ((mouseY - yp)/3);
    $("#circle").css('transform', 'translate(' + xp + 'px, ' + yp + 'px)');
  }, 20);

});
```